# How to place page on top after the reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var $form = $('form');
$form.submit(function() {
  $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
    alert("Your form is submitted");
    location.reload();
  }, 'json');
  return false;
});
```

How do I place the user at the top of the page after I forced `location.reload();` ?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by place page on top?

Comment: I force the page reload after submitting the form, which is at the bottom of the page, way bellow the fold. After the reload I want page to 'land' at the top, but currently it is landing on form.

Comment: post your html and css, or even better, a demo page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('body').scrollTop(0);
location.reload();
```

That will take the page to the top after your alert and then reload which will load the page where it left off (at the top in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Use this code on your page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```

That will scroll page on top after reload.

Answer (score 1):

Write following code before 'location.reload();'

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```